# TypeError: subcollection.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore and making comment section
so that user can leave comment for post.

some code I found below:

```
 export function saveComment(comment, id, uid) {
     // database = firebase.database().ref('posts/');
     return dispatch => database.child(id).child('comments').push({ 
     content: comment.content, uid })
   }
```

The code above using realtime database and I cannot use child() as Cloud Firestore.

Here's my code:

postActions.js

```
export const addComment = (postId, comment) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const profile = getState().firebase.profile;
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const ref = firestore.doc("posts/"+postId);
    const subcollection = ref.collection('comments')
    subcollection.push(comment)
  };
};
```

Instead of child(), What kind of function, I need to use? in Cloud Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push()` method you found is from the Firebase Realtime Database API, while you are using Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate and each has their own API.

To add a new document to a Cloud Firestore collection, use the `add` method on its `CollectionReference`. So:

```
subcollection.add(comment)
```

See the [Firestore documentation on adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

Comment: Good to hear. Be sure to study the Firestore documentation for a bit, since an hour or so spent there, will save a multitude of that time down the line.